# LESS nested rule with inherit parameters

Tags: html, css, less, webmatrix

I would like to know if LESS admit this kind of operation with variables:

```
.class(@A, @B)
{
    color: @A;
    background: @B;

    &:hover
    {
         color: @B;
         background: @A;
    }
}
```

Because when doing it, Web Matrix 3 throws me the following error inside the :hover section: "Undeclared variable"

If is not admitted, which can be a possible solution?

Thank you all in advance.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bug in WebMatrix; your LESS is perfectly valid.

You can make it shorter like this:

```
.class(@A, @B)
{
    &, &:hover
    {
         color: @B;
         background: @A;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I use other IDE and/or compiler?

Comment: @FedericoMaza: Visual Studio (especially 2013, and especially with Web Essentials) is very nice.  It still has some bugs, but those are supposed to be fixed by the 2013 RTM.

Comment: Your reduced code is not the same output as the OP's original question. Notice that he flips the colors on `:hover` whereas yours keeps the same colors for the two states.